# SQL Bulk data duplicate check

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application which will find the duplicates from the records from a billing information table. Each process contain approx 50K records.

Table and result view

[image]

```html
In the above picture, highlighted are the result cols and here what I did is , 
Amount Paid Dup == Duplicate count of col 'Amount Paid', 
AmountBilled Dup == Duplicate count of col 'AmountBilled',
Invoice Number WO Alpha Dup == Duplicate count of col value 'Invoice Number' without alpha,
Bill Number Dup == Duplicate count of col 'Bill Number',
Invoice and Bill Number Dup == Combined Duplicate count of col 'Invoice number and Bill Number'.
```

Like above I need to check the duplicates of 6 cols and I used merge into and with statements, but it taking too much time to process the doc. Please suggest the best method to process similar duplicate check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) sql command ?

Without knowing the tables structures I can't give you a code example

Comment: above mentioned in the image is the table structure. Other than above cols, I have an ID col and removed the _ from col name. 

Also, let me check the  INTERSECT sql command